# Using global context as "DI container" in NodeJS and Typescript

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection

I've been reading about DI in Nodejs, but apart from using containers, using a framework or building one yourself, there's no "quick" way to implement DI. So I thought about initialising the dependencies in app.ts and add them to the global context and use them within my routes.

It would look something like this

```
// app.ts

const app = express();

const initDeps = (): Deps => {
    return {
        authController: new AuthService(),
    }
}
global.deps = initDeps();

app.use('/auth', authRouter);
```

Then on auth Router:

```
const authRouter = require('express').Router();

const authController = new AuthController(global.deps.authService);

authRouter.post('/signup', signupValidator, authController.signUp);
```

Is it a feasible pattern or are there downsides to this approach?

Comment: This is just the service locator pattern but as a global object. Service locator is already a bad pattern as it makes it very hard to track down which dependency is used where and what changing a dependency would impact. Or if a dependency can be removed as no longer needed.

Comment: Wouldn't that be similar as using libraries like typedi?

Comment: I'm not familiar with typedi. If it's just a service locator (read: object you have to pull what you want from and you pass that object around for each thing to pull its own dependencies from it), then it's not good.

Comment: Would you argue then that Angular or NestJS for instance are not good choices because they use the service locator pattern in their core? I would love to hear your opinion on that.

Comment: Are *you* dealing with the service locator? Because that's where the problem is. As an application scales, the service locator gets in the way of properly understanding and reasoning about it. But if somebody else decided to deal with this and you just consume their API, then that doesn't get transferred to your code, obviously. You're not dealing with their scaling, after all. Besides, I was under the impression Angular used proper dependency injection, rather than a locator. But even if it doesn't - again, doesn't matter to you as a consumer if you don't deal with it.

Comment: I understand your point. It would be worthwhile figuring out how to do DI in Node (in the routes) without using a service locator. Thank you sir